# How can I retrieve the raw JSON payload passed to a Spring Boot POST API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a **Spring Boot** project in which I have to develop an API handling **POST** request that contains a JSON payload.

I was looking to this example documentation: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-resttemplate-post-json

in which it is done:

```
@PostMapping(
  value = "/createPerson", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Person createPerson(@RequestBody Person person) {
    return personService.saveUpdatePerson(person);
}
```

Basing on my understanding this API is expecting a JSON payload into the body of the request (because I have the **consumes = "application/json"** into the **@PostMapping** annotation) that will be automatically converted into an instance of **Person** class.

Is it this reasoning correct?

If my reasoning is correct I have a doubt: my specific use case is pretty different: my API doesn't know what kind of object represents the JSON payload (for example it could be a **Person**, an **Animal** or a **Thing**). So the API can't figured out in what kind of object serialize the received JSON.

So what I was thinking to do is:

1. The API have to receive the raw JSON payload in some way.
2. Basing on the JSON content it creates the appropriate object (for example an instance of **Person** or an instance of **Animal**).

It could be a smart solution? 
What have I to do to retrieve the raw JSON payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: `Map<String, Object>`**

If you just need the JSON String use Map instead of Person. Then no transformation from JSON to an object will happen.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createPerson", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Map<String, Object> createPerson(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> json) {
     // Do whatever you want to do
}
```

As you can see this method also returns a Map so you could return a JSON String as well

**Option 2: String**

You could also use String. Make sure that consumes is set to MediaType.ALL_VALUE

```
@PostMapping(value = "demo", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String createPerson(@RequestBody String json) {
     // Do whatever you want to do
    return json;
}
```

Comment: in this case you will force users to send String instead of Json

Answer (score 0):

try to use HttpEntity to get raw body as String then convert it to your custom Object:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/createPerson", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Person createPerson(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity) {
    String body= httpEntity.getBody();
    // convert your String to Person object or what ever using ObjectMapper
    // ...
    return personService.saveUpdatePerson(person);
}
```

Comment: Your solution does not work Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class org.springframework.http.HttpEntity<java.lang.String>]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "lastModified":